# For loop returning error when trying to loop through list with beauifulsoup

Tags: pandas, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a loop that will loop though locations and extract out the necessary data and append it to the rest of the locations.

I feel that the code I have written is good but keep getting an error of:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

but I know that shouldn't be the case.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests


locations = ['las-vegas-nv','denver-co']
for location in locations:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }



    url = 'https://www.apartments.com/{location}/1-bedrooms/'
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find("table", class_="rentTrendGrid")
    rows = []

    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all(['th', 'td'])])

#header_row = rows[0]
    rows = list(zip(*rows[0:])) # tranpose the table
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
    df['City'] = location
    dfs.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: You're missing `f' '` in `url = f'https://www.apartments.com/{location}/1-bedrooms/'`

Comment: Great, I knew it would be something simple....thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Andrej was right, super simple just had to put the 'f' in front.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests


locations = ['las-vegas-nv','denver-co']
for location in locations:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }



    url = f'https://www.apartments.com/{location}/1-bedrooms/'
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find("table", class_="rentTrendGrid")
    rows = []

    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        rows.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all(['th', 'td'])])

#header_row = rows[0]
    rows = list(zip(*rows[0:])) # tranpose the table
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
    df['City'] = location
    dfs.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop = True)
print(df)
```